# Xml Requests do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I cannot get a bare bones Asp.Net Core Web Api project to work using Xml instead of Json. Please help!

I have created a new project and the only adjustments to the default configuration were to add the Xml formatters...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```

My Controller also contains simple Get and Post methods:

```
[Route("api")]
public class MessageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Message message)
    {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new Message
        {
            TestProperty = "Test value"
        });
    }
}
```

When I try calling the `POST` method with `Content-Type: application/xml`, the API returns 415 Unsupported Media Type. I have tried adding the `Consumes("application/xml")` attribute to the controller and still it does not work.

The GET works and returns JSON. However, if I add the `Produces("application/xml")` attribute to the controller, the GET returns 406  Not Acceptable, even if I provide the `Accepts: application/xml` header.

For some reason, the API is completely rejecting anything related to xml even though the input and output formatters were added as I have seen in the very few examples I could find.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should this not work with XML by default without having to add anything?

Comment: No, by default Asp.Net core only includes the Json Formatters. The Xml Formatters need to be explicitly added. Except they do not work apparently...

Comment: @frangelico87 Did you try to set `config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;`. According to this article(https://wildermuth.com/2016/03/16/Content_Negotiation_in_ASP_NET_Core) it is needed.

Comment: Yes. From my understanding, that is only required for specifying the response format. Either way, yes I have tried that and it also does not work.

Comment: @frangelico87 For input formatter official docs says that use `services.AddMvc() .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();` . see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body

Comment: @ademcaglin Tried that already also. I believe that is just supposed to be an extension method that does the same thing

Answer (score 9):

I have following thing in my startup.cs and it works well with XML and JSON both. 
Here I only stick with XML.
Note : ( I have consider my own class for sample)

1. Startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       { 
           services.AddMvcCore()
                   .AddJsonFormatters().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
       }
   ```
2. My HttpClient Code ( You might have missed Content Type setting that I have done in StringCotent)

   - Two header is important : Accept and Content-Type. Accept help in content negotiation and Content-Type is a way client tell server what type content client is posting.

     ```
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri( @"http://localhost:5000");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));


      HttpContent content = new StringContent(@"<Product>
     <Id>122</Id>
     <Name>Computer112</Name></Product>",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 , "application/xml");  // This is important.

     var result = client.PostAsync("/api/Products", content).Result;
     ```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but I think that only `Content-Type: application/xml` should be important for POST because the return value `void`. The `Accept: application/xml` could be important for GET. Moreover one can consider to use `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters` instead of `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` because it supports more datatypes (like `Dictionary`).

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.Net Core 2.0 you can accept both XML and Json request almost out of the box.

In Startup class in ConfigureServices method, you should have:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

And controller that accepts complex object looks like this:

```
[Route("api/Documents")]
public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    [Route("SendDocument")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendDocument([FromBody]DocumentDto document)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is an XML to send:

```
<document>
    <id>123456</id>
<content>This is document that I posted...</content>
<author>Michał Białecki</author>
<links>
    <link>2345</link>
    <link>5678</link>
</links>
```

```
{
    id: "1234",
    content: "This is document that I posted...",
    author: "Michał Białecki",
    links: {
        link: ["1234", "5678"]
    }
}
```

And that’s it! It just works.

[image: .net core debugging]

Request with the same document either in XML or Json to api/documents/SendDocument endpoint is handled by one method. Only remember about correct Content-Type header in your request.

You can read the whole post at my blog: http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/25/accept-xml-request-in-asp-net-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET Core 2.2 use nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml** or **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App**
and add this in Startup.cs

```
      services.AddMvc()
       .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
       .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Don't forget to use headers **Accept application/xml** to get response as xml and **Content-Type application/xml** for request with xml body.

Check example here http://www.devcode4.com/article/asp-net-core-xml-request-response

Answer (score 0):

asp.net core 8:

builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

Not supplied by default if a new Web Api project.

Then

```
[HttpPost()]
[Route("/api/ze/postxml")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public ActionResult PostXml([FromBody] TestIntrant test)
{

    return new JsonResult(new { resultat = "ok" });

}
```

Witout this you get: 415 Unsupported Media Type